# Getting datas from JSON file with Json.NET and create c-sharp file with using T4 Text Template

Tags: c#, json, json.net, t4

I want to create `Subject.cs` file programmatically. For this, when I searched the Internet, I saw that I could use T4 Text Templates. Now, I want to get datas from a JSON file with Json.NET and set the `Root` values as a property, like this:

```
namespace Library
{
    class Subject
    {
        public static int forensic_medicine { get; set; }
        public static int family_law { get; set; }
        public static int constitutional_law { get; set; }
        public static int obligations_law { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON file content:

```
{
    "Subjects": [
        {
            "Root": "forensic_medicine",
            "Name": "Forensic Medicine",
            "StrID": "FMD",
            "RowID": 746
        },
        {
            "Root": "family_law",
            "Name": "Family Law",
            "StrID": "FML",
            "RowID": 1239
        },
        {
            "Root": "constitutional_law",
            "Name": "Constitutional Law",
            "StrID": "CNL",
            "RowID": 996
        },
        {
            "Root": "obligations_law",
            "Name": "Obligations Law",
            "StrID": "OBL",
            "RowID": 1672
        }
    ],
    "is_restart": 0,
    "book_path": "D:\\Colin\\_books\\",
    "thesis_path": "D:\\Colin\\_thesises\\",
    "full_screen": false
}
```

I think, I must use `SubjectList` and `Subject` classes for reading and getting datas from JSON file. For this, I am using classes like this:

```
public class SubjectList
{
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string StrID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Root { get; set; }
    public int RowID { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, for getting datas, I am using code like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubjectList>(File.ReadAllText("D:\\Colin\\_test\\inf.json"));
```

In the Text Template file (`Subjects.tt`), the codes are here:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Test\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
namespace Library
{
    public class Subject
    {
        <#
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubjectList>(File.ReadAllText("D:\\Colin\\_test\\inf.json"));
        #>
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors without doing anything else.

`Compiling transformation: The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context`

`Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'SubjectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I think I have to use `SubjectList` and `Subject` classes in the `Subjects.tt` file, but I don't know how I do it. More importantly, how can I create `Subject.cs` file programmatically without getting any problem?

Comment: Change the class name in which you are deserializing the JSON. Apparently, both classes have the same name `Subject`.

Answer (score 6):

To use any reference that's in an assembly (whether a NuGet package like Newtonsoft.Json or even project output), you must add an import **and** assembly directives. In your case specifically, try to add the referenced assembly by simply using the assembly name directly. On a side note, it would also be good to read in your json file relative to the text template itself. Example:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ assembly name="Newtonsoft.Json" #>
<#@ import namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" #>
<#@ import namespace="Newtonsoft.Json.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    string templateFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.Host.TemplateFile);
    string settingsPath = this.Host.ResolvePath($"{templateFileName}.json");
    string settingsJson = File.ReadAllText(settingsPath);
    var datasource = JObject.Parse(settingsJson);
#>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you need to add an extra `<#@ import namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" #>` for the Newtonsoft namespace